# What causes a fatal: not a git repository error?

Tags: wordpress, git, google-app-engine

I am working on webpage, and I need version tracking, so I'm uploading it to github.

Here is the underlying set up.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

Now that I have the base CMS ready to go, I need to get the base code uploaded before I start making changes.

```
lloydm@lloydm-E6320:~/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code$ pwd
/home/lloydm/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code
lloydm@lloydm-E6320:~/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   wordpress/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
lloydm@lloydm-E6320:~/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code$ ls
app.yaml  cron.yaml  php.ini  wordpress
lloydm@lloydm-E6320:~/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code$ git add .
fatal: Not a git repository: wordpress/wp-content/plugins/../.git/modules/appengine-wordpress-plugin
```

I've never used github before, so I was just following the github website stuff. I have zero idea what this error means or how to prevent it. I can't find anything that I think is related to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your git repo correctly.

I think you followed this section "Installing WordPress on your development environment" from the link you provided https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

So what you did was download WordPress into your folder which you set up to be a .git repository.  However, the WordPress project builder you downloaded itself contains a .git repository.

Check if you have a /workpress/.git file.  It likely contains something like :

> gitdir: ../.git/modules/wordpress

If you do, then that explains the error I think.

As for setting it up correctly, there are many tutorials available.

One way is to use Git for theme deployment, rather than having it manage your entire WordPress installation  --> http://culttt.com/2013/04/08/how-to-deploy-wordpress-themes-with-git/

Another way is to add wordpress as a submodule http://www.efeqdev.com/website-development/this-is-how-we-version-control-and-deploy-our-wordpress-websites-with-git/

or Just make a ~/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code/wordpress/myWebpage directory and set up a git repo in it. http://www.whistlenet.com/git-for-wordpress/

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense. So I should likely just download the WP source from git, make my changes, and then upload it to my repo?

Comment: Well.  Actually your current WP installation is fine.  Just make a ~/Downloads/rtt/rtt-code/wordpress/myWebpage directory and set up a git repo in it.  That's what the last link I added does.

Comment: I just did a git pull against the official WP repo, and then just pushed it to my repo. Worked easier, less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to go into the wordpress folder and then run the git status command. As the directory(rtt-code) is not a git directory but contains within it the git repo, that is wordpress, you are getting this error.

Inside the wordpress folder, all your git commands would work perfectly well...

Comment: Well that's fine for changing WordPress itself right, but the files for your project aren't kept in the WordPress installation folder are they?